# How can i write the following code without for loops in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, tail-recursion

I need help with the following program in javascript

A function, written without any loop statements, that accepts an array and produces a new array equal to the initial array with ith element (1-based) repeated i times.

i was able to write the code in for loop, just need help in writing without loop

```
export function stretched(a) {
    const stretchedArray = [];
    for (let [index, item] of a.entries()) {
      for (let i = 0; i < index + 1; i++) {
        stretchedArray.push(item);
      }
    }
    return stretchedArray;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework?  Presumably, if you're supposed to do it without `for` loops, then you will need to use array methods for the iteration such as `.map()` or `.forEach()` or `.reduce()` or `.filter()`.

Comment: No, I am doing a course online , I am new to JavaScript. working on problem set given and yes the question states to use without loops.

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Well, there is no way to iterate an array with loops.  You can iterate with a `for` loop, but all those other methods I mentioned are all loops too.

Answer (score 0):

This can be another approach:

```js
function stretched(a) {
    const stretchedArray = [];
    for (let [index, item] of a.entries()) {
      stretchedArray.push(...(new Array(index + 1).fill(item)))
    }
    return stretchedArray;
}

console.log(stretched(['a','b','c']))
```